# Can Telnet connect to a path?

Tags: networking, telnet

I'm being told that I should expect to be able to telnet to an address in the form `subdomain.domain.tld/path`. This seems like an odd "host" for telnet to accept. Is there particular flags or something I'd need to be able to connect to such a target? Should it just work?
For instance:
`telnet mysub.mydomain.tld 1234` is working.
`telnet mysub.mydomain.tld/path 1234` is not.
This seems to make sense to me, I've never before encountered two connections separated by a path like this. They've always been on different parts if they share the same subdomain.
Is there some way I could verify this from outside the system hosting this? I am working with a client that is not providing much in the way of information or further assistance unless I specifically ask and in this case I am not sure what to even ask.

Comment: the thing you are missing is that telnet connects to a program, and programs expose connectivity via ports. when you put a URL in a browser, you are connecting to the web server process on tcp\80, and then the web server parses the path and gives it meaning. a program might or might not expose additional addressing components internally, but all telnet as a client is prepared to deal with is `server port`.

Comment: Thanks, but I was of the understanding that was true. I was wondering if there was something **else** I was missing to provide a way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone who used telnet to connect to talkers & muds before finding a mud client, I've never heard of connecting to a path, and the man pages indicate, there is no support for connecting to a path, just a host.

Quoting from the man page for telnet, as found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/telnet)

> open host [-l user] [ [-] port]
>   Open a connection to the named host.
>   If no port number is specified, telnet will attempt to contact a
>   TELNET server at the default port. The host specification may be
>   either a host name (see hosts(5)) or an Internet address specified in
>   the ''dot notation'' (see inet(3)). The -l option may be used to
>   specify the user name to be passed to the remote system via the
>   ENVIRON option. When connecting to a non-standard port, telnet omits
>   any automatic initiation of TELNET options. When the port number is
>   preceded by a minus sign, the initial option negotiation is done.
>   After establishing a connection, the file .telnetrc in the user's home
>   directory is opened. Lines beginning with a ''#'' are comment lines.
>   Blank lines are ignored. Lines that begin without whitespace are the
>   start of a machine entry. The first thing on the line is the name of
>   the machine that is being connected to. The rest of the line, and
>   successive lines that begin with whitespace are assumed to be telnet
>   commands and are processed as if they had been typed in manually to
>   the telnet command prompt.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel It's possible they actually want you to use a web browser to connect to that location with a non-standard port, or use telnet to do some sort of testing of a web server. Other than that, I can't imagine what they might be thinking.

Comment: I wanted to know if it was possible, you answered that. My reasoning for asking was more curiosity. Later, I discovered they were in fact simply wrong (as suspected) and that they did in fact mean to have a different port on the same host. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

No, telneting to a path doesn’t make sense.